# Почему MinGW искажает RBP?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw, x86-64

Мне захотелось написать свой stack walker. Его я-то написал, но столкнулся с проблемой внедрения возможности считывать регистры стека из другого потока. Моя *примерная* реализация:

```c
...
if (thrd) {
    CONTEXT ctx;
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    GetThreadContext(thrd, &ctx);
    rbp = ctx.Rbp;
} else {
    register uintptr_t _rbp asm("rbp");
    rbp = _rbp + 0x480; // добавление
}
...
```

Если считываем из другого потока, то выделяем место под контекст, а потом считываем. Но только после добавления этого кода все тесты слетели и перестали работать: трассировка просто не выводилась, а они были для текущего потока (т.е. я просто прогнал старые тесты с `thrd == 0`). В итоге я пришёл к выводу, что MinGW в прологе функции, которая устанавливает регистры, генерирует след. код:

```
pushq   %rbp
subq    $1296, %rsp
leaq    128(%rsp), %rbp
```

Ожидалось такое:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    ..., %rsp
```

Он зачем-то приписывает 3-ю строчку, хотя не должен, и RBP получается искажённым. В коде я добавил к его рабочей копии `0x480`, и всё вернулось на круги своя.

3-я строчка возникает только при выделении памяти в стеке под `CONTEXT`, в противном случае добавление не требуется.

Я думал, что это какая-то очередная оптимизация или что-то типа того. Вот с какими опциями я компилировал:

```
-g -shared -fPIC -mwindows -march=x86-64
```

Включал-выключал `-g` — ничего не меняется. Как избавиться от этого `leaq`?

---

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f() {
    CONTEXT a;
    CONTEXT b;
    register uintptr_t rbp asm("rbp");

    printf("rbp: %p *rbp: %p\n", rbp, *(void **)rbp);
}
int main() {
    f();
}
```

Вот вам такой же пример: комментируете строчки с выделением памяти в стеке под контексты, и получаете разный вывод.

Только если закомментить оба контекста `*rbp` будет находится в районе стека, в остальных случаях он равен какому-то мусору.

<sub>Вывод</sub>

```
rbp: 000000000061FDF0 *rbp: 000000000061FE20 // закомменчены оба
rbp: 000000000061F980 *rbp: 0000000000702520 // закомменчен 1
rbp: 000000000061F4B0 *rbp: 0000000000060000 // ни один не закомменчен
```

Comment: `Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой` - я не прошу помочь с отладкой, я прошу помочь с причиной, как мне кажется, неправильного поведения компилятора. я привёл пример, в котором описано, при каких условиях компилятор так себя ведёт. я не прошу помочь с отладкой: я сам уже узнал, в чём проблема (в общем случае, скорее всего, корнем проблемы является большое выделение памяти в стеке). я спрашиваю, как эту проблему решить.

Comment: Нет, вы не привели пример. Вы кинули какой-то огрызок кода, который крайне далек от [mcve] и не позволяет читателям вопроса воспроизвести заявленное поведение.

Comment: @user7860670 вот пример, который можно скомпилировать и запустить

Comment: так что не так? при появлении локальных переменных rbp уменьшается, чтобы их разместить

Comment: обнулите контексты и *rbp будет указывать на 0

Comment: @PavelGridin 1) выделение памяти в стеке осуществляется уменьшением rsp, почему уменьшается rbp? зачем? 2) обнулением контекстов ничего не решишь: память всё равно выделяется 3) *rbp не будет указывать на 0. что значит указывать на 0? т.е. по адресу, хранящемуся в rbp будет хранится указатель, который указывает на нулевой адрес? число в графе `*rbp` должно быть в пределах стека и не должно "указывать на 0". если `*rbp` за пределами стека, то это первый фрейм стека; поэтому я и добавил функцию `f`, чтобы это был 2-й фрейм и *rbp не был каким-то мусорным значением во всех случаях

Comment: @return, да перепутал c sp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ожидалось

Ваши ожидания - ваши проблемы (c)

Существует документация по "Windows x64 calling conventions" и иже с ними. Из нее следует, что frame pointer (если он вообще используется) должен указывать в конец fixed allocation (т.е. *после* всех `auto` и до `alloca()`), а не туда куда вы подумали.

Что касается смещения 128, то это такая допустимая оптимизация. Позволяет генератору кода использовать косвенную адресацию `[base+index+byte]` в стиле "труЪ modR/M без энтих ваших новомодных SIB'ов".

Comment: хорошо, rbp может быть "после всех `auto` и до `alloca`", но тут 2 вопроса: 1) как тогда вообще сделать трассировку стека в таких условиях 2) как убрать эту "оптимизацию"

Comment: @return Не положено. Все должны пользоваться WinAPI. Погуглите чего-нибудь по теме. CaptureStackBackTrace, dbghelp.h и пр. и пр.

Comment: да, я об этом знаю, я просто для большего "погружения" хотел написать свой stack trace. просто у меня в голове пока не укладывается, как тогда ссылаться на пред. фрейм, если rbp может содержать что угодно? до этого у меня в голове были только ответики с enSO, где весь пролог был 3-х строчным `push`-`mov`-`sub`. тут же rbp как-то "оптимизируется" и не понятно, как найти  базу фрейма

Comment: @return 1. Оптимизации тут ни при чем. Будет bp указывать на "конец", или "конец+128", или вообще `-fomit-frame-pointer` - адрес возврата все равно отсюда не выжать. 2. Машинный код... хм-м, машинно же и зависим.  Появление bp - это особенность еще 8086, когда косвенная регистровая адресация была только вида base+index. А теперь каким регистром хочешь, таким и адресуй. Компилятору же проще всего считать от текущего rsp и вообще не париться. Так что особой ценности "frame pointer" в наше время не представляет.

Comment: да, rbp вообще какой-то бесполезный получается... для решения моей задачи, естественно. жаль, что microsoft не хотят публиковать код WinAPI, так бы этого вопроса не было, т.к. не возникло бы подобной проблемы... ладно, `StackWalk64` всему голова

Comment: @return, я бы посмотрел на сорсы gdb. Они же умеют стек раскручивать

Comment: @avp <strike>Не читал, но осуждаю</strike> Не смотрел, но предполагаю, что под виндой они все через WinAPI и делают.